# Parseing regex with groups and subgroups?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this text:

```
*   Ikke 26/12 11.
**  Ikke 24/12 11.
*** Ikke 22/8 11. Ikke 29/8 11. Ikke 5/9 11. Ikke 12/9 11. Ikke 19/9 11. Ikke 26/9 11. Ikke 3/10 11. Ikke 10/10 11. Ikke 17/10 11. Ikke 24/10 11. Ikke 31/10 11. Ikke 7/11 11. Ikke 14/11 11. Ikke 21/11 11. Ikke 28/11 11. Ikke 5/12 11. Ikke12/12 11. Ikke 19/12 11.
****    Ikke 25/12 11.
```

And I am trying to write a regex expression to obain all the asterixes and the dates. But I need to know the number of asterixes that came before.

So far I have come up with `(?<Stars>\**)*(?<Date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2} \d{2})` but for some reason it wont find the asterixes.

I know I can split the text first, but I would like to try with regex only

Comment: what do you want in an output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off doing matching on something like

```
(?m)^(?<Stars>\*+)|(?<Date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2} \d{2})
```

And every match see if you got the stars (first group is defined), or the date. If you have the stars save it in a variable for later use. When date matches check the previously stored star var.

Comment: this only gets the first star... it doesn't get subsequent ones.. but getting rid of the "^" at the beginning would make it work.

Comment: It gets all stars, forgot to mention that you need the multiline flag, or just add `(?m)` to the beginning of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted

```
(?<Stars>\**)
```

not

```
(?<Stars>\**)*
```

This would possibly 'clobber' the latest match of asterisks with an 'empty run' (because * allow 0 or more).

Alternatively:

```
(?<Stars>\*+)?
```

(match 1 or more `*` - optionally)

Answer (score 0):

This should work... essentially you had nothing saying ignore stuff between the date and the stars...

```
(?<Stars>[*]*)(?<ignore>.*?)(?<Date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2} \d{2})
```

Answer (score 0):

here :

```
(?<astrix>[\*]+)|(?<Date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2} \d{2})
```

http://regexr.com?2vc8s